# Remote gem is not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I got this when I tried to update gems:

```
LJ$ gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name
```

and this when trying to install a gem:

```
LJ$ gem install mongrel
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mongrel' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Probably your internet connection is bad or the gem repository is down.

Comment: Are you able to access the url https://rubygems.org/gems/mongrel from the host you are trying to install the package at?

Comment: This is technically not programming related at all

Comment: @digitalextremist Correct.  It's a question about "tools commonly used by programmers."  Such questions are, provided they are well asked, on topic.

Comment: I restarted my computer and then it worked.